# How to use list params in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

It contains error "inferred type s for parameter s is not within its bound". help me pls.

```java
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer>{}
public interface ProductServiceInterface { void addListProducts(List<Product> productList);}
@Service
    public class ProductService implements ProductServiceInterface{
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Override
    public void addListProducts(List<Product> productList) {
        productRepository.save(productList);
    }
}
public class Product { private int id; private String name; //Getter&Setter}
```

Comment: is it working for one record instead of a list?

Comment: yes, it can work for one record but doesn't work by list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58831074/5993197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `saveAll(productList)`
as you are saving a list of products not an object, save is used for an object.you can see [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-batch-inserts#howto) too

Comment: If it solves your problem, accept it by clicking tick sign that is below to votes arrows.